# This JavaScript works on chrome but not on Safari and Firefox, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I'm making this very simple web based RPG ([source available in Github](https://github.com/Mouradif/webRPG)), you can see it here :

http://odelaria.it-zone.ma

So basicly for the login script, I have this `login()` function that's supposed to fire on form submit, it retrieves the values of the form fields and ajaxly send it to my server-side script then according to the response logs the player in the game without reloading the page. It is working perfectly on Chrome but I've just found out that in Safari and Firefox the form submits and reloads the page. I also tried calling `login();` from the console after filling the form, I get a "wrong login" message.

You can try with these credentials :

```
login : test, pass : test
```

or

```
login : test2, pass : 12345
```

and please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Does your onsubmit handler return false?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Hello j08691, the Github repository can always be checked out for the date of the question. The code is large and since it works on Chrome and doesn't throw any error on other browsers, it would be hard to find a minimal example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to put your javascript includes (from `index.html`) at the bottom of the page (before `</body>`)

Answer (score -2):

Looking into `main.js` I have found the following piece of code:

```
_('f_form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    login(1);
}, true);
```

Provide the submit button with `id` attribute f.e:

```
<input id="f_form_submit" type="submit" value="Connexion">...
```

Change above sourcecode by the following:

```
_('f_form_submit').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    login(1);
}, true);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to return false in `onsubmit` event handler:

```
<form id="f_form" method="get" onsubmit="return false">
</form>
```